# Retrofit. Application keep stopping

Tags: android, retrofit

If you specify a URL path in the request, the application closes when the connection to the api is called. If you write without parameters, the application sends a request and I get a response. What could be the reason ?

URL path: {phone}

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("Register?app=CxTaxiWebAPI&phone={phone}")
    Call<List<PhoneNumber>> registration(@Path("phone") String phoneNumber);
}
```

dependencies:

```
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
```

request:

```
public void EnterCodeOnClick(View view) {

apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

Call<List<PhoneNumber>> call = apiInterface.registration("34");

call.enqueue(new Callback<List<PhoneNumber>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<PhoneNumber>> call, Response<List<PhoneNumber>> response) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " +  response.body());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<PhoneNumber>> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getLocalizedMessage() );
    }
});
```

Comment: share error....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
@GET("Register?app=CxTaxiWebAPI")
  Call<List<PhoneNumber>> registration(@Query("phone") String phone);
```

Comment: It worked ! But why ? Thanks ! But when I change the version of the dependencies, the application crashes anyway. Is this a bug in Retrofit?